# Is there any user control on QGIS recent project list?

Tags: qgis, configuration, user-interface

I know I can delete a project from the recent projects list, but is there any user-accessible control on how many projects are shown by default in this list? I have looked in Settings and also in documentation and I'm none the wiser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the number of recent projects in the list. Open the advanced settings editor:

Settings -> Options -> Advanced (promise to be careful)

Open the "app" category and you'll see a setting for "maxRecentProjects" that defaults to 20. Adjust the value and restart QGIS.

[image]

I'm running 3.24.1-Tisler on Ubuntu.